# angularjs - ng-repeat: access key and value from JSON array object

Tags: json, angularjs

I have JSON Array object as shown below.

```
$scope.items = 
    [
    {Name: "Soap",  Price: "25",  Quantity: "10"},
    {Name: "Bag",   Price: "100", Quantity: "15"},
    {Name: "Pen",   Price: "15",  Quantity: "13"}
];
```

I want to get the keys and values separately using ng-repeat in angular.js. I have tried the following code but its not working.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in items">
  <td>{{key}}</td> 
  <td>{{val}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I believe the problem is with the braces '[' and ']'. Can anyone please suggest me how the issue can be resolved ?

## Edited:

Thank you so much for the reply. I have tried your code and its working. But my real requirement is display the items as shown below.

```
Name     Price  Quantity
Soap        25  10
Bag        100  15
Pen         15  13
```

I am using some `<tr>` and `<td>` in html. But nothing getting displayd in screen. The codes are shown below.

```
<table>  
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{val}}</td>
  </tr>
</tr> 
</table>
```

I know that `<tr>` inside of another `<tr>` is not permitted by html. I tried by best.But no luck.
It will be great if you could help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55):

You've got an array of objects, so you'll need to use `ng-repeat` twice, like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
  <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
    {{key}}: {{val}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/

### Edit:

Note that properties order in objects are not guaranteed.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in items[0]">{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">{{val}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/2/

Comment: @AjithBalakrishnan: Not best practice (properties order in objects are not guaranted), but here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/2/

Comment: Thanks, this tip of using ng-repeat twice helped with a JSON array parsing that I was struggling with. :)

Answer (score 7):

I have just started checking out Angular(so im quite sure there are other ways to get it done which are more optimum), and i came across this question while searching for examples of ng-repeat.

The requirement by the poser(with the update):

> "...but my real requirement is display the items as shown below.."

looked real-world enough (and simple), so i thought ill give it a spin and attempt to get the exact desired structure.

```js
angular.module('appTest', [])
  .controller("repeatCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      Name: "Soap",
      Price: "25",
      Quantity: "10"
    }, {
      Name: "Bag",
      Price: "100",
      Quantity: "15"
    }, {
      Name: "Pen",
      Price: "15",
      Quantity: "13"
    }];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="appTest">
  <section ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:1">
          <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
            {{key}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
            {{val}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</body>
```

The limitTo:(n) filter is the key. Im still not sure if having multiple ng-repeat is an optimum way to go about it, but can't think of another alternative currently.

Answer (score 3):

Solution
I have json object which has data

```
[{"name":"Ata","email":"test@test1.com"}]
```

You can use following approach to iterate through ng-repeat and use table format instead of list.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="fetchdataCtrl">    
  <ul ng-repeat="item in numbers">
    <li>            
      {{item.name}}: {{item.email}}
    </li>
  </ul>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
<td>{{item.Name}}</td>
<td>{{item.Price}}</td>
<td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```