# AngulaJS filter on array of object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this JSON object.

```
 var UsersList=[ 
    {
       "User" : {

          "IdUser" : "admin",
          "FirstName" : "mirco",
          "LastName" : "sabatino"

       }
    }, {
       "User" : {

          "IdUser" : "coordinator",
          "FirstName" : "coordinator",
          "LastName" : ""

       }
    }, {
       "User" : {

          "IdUser" : "test",
          "FirstName" : "publisher",
          "LastName" : "Diaz"

       }
    }, {
       "User" : {

          "IdUser" : "work",
          "FirstName" : "ingester",
          "LastName" : "Brown"

       }
    } 
    ] ;
```

I want filter in ng-repeat for `LastName` value.

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="users in UsersList | filter: {User.LastName : filterSearchLetter}">
```

`filterSearchLetter` value in my controler is populated by

```
$scope.filterLetterUser=function(letter){
       $scope.filterSearchLetter=letter;
       console.log($scope.filterSearchLetter);
    };
```

But this don't work.

Comment: how do you want get 'letter'

Answer (score 1):

See my plnkr for the solution http://plnkr.co/edit/l27xUQ?p=preview. I also have implemented your required UI behavior using ng-change. Hope it helps.

For detailed explanation I offer you Todd Motto's blog - http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

To invoke a filter, the syntax is the filter function name followed by the parameters.

To define a filter you need to do (This is copy of Todd Motto's code modified for your data)

```
todos.filter('startsWithLetter', function () {
    return function (items, letter) {
        var filtered = [];
        var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (letterMatch.test(item.User.LastName.substring(0, 1))) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid object:  `{User.LastName : filterSearchLetter}` It should actually throw an exception saying something like

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

What you probably want to try instead is: `{"User": {"LastName" : filterSearchLetter} }`

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over an array of Objects see:
[angularjs - ng-repeat: access key and value from JSON array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697695/angularjs-ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-from-json-array-object)

You may have to convert to valid JS object using JS_Obj=JSON.parse(JSON_Obj);

Maybe something like this:

```
//iterate through array
<ul ng-repeat="users in UsersList">
  //iterate through Object
  <li ng-repeat=(key, value) in users | filter: {User.LastName : filterSearchLetter}>
     {{key}} : {{value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```