# Ng-repeat to render data with key-value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON structure like:

```
"Address": {
        "Address1": [
          "Lane1",
          "Lane2"
        ]
}
```

I want to render the values in a table using ng-repeat.

```
<td ng-repeat="(key,value) in results">{{value}}</td>
```

This is displaying the data as `["Lane1", "Lane2"]` within the table.

How do I properly display the data in table without the array braces using ng-repeat eg: `Lane1,Lane2` ?

I need to display both the values and not just one value, which i am able to achieve using `{{value[0]}}`

Comment: It looks like the data your iterating over is the array value of `Address1` not the object properties of `Address` in which case your would just use `ng-repeat="result in results"`. Not an object. If you can provide more of your table markup and JavaScript we may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697695/angularjs-ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-from-json-array-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat with (key, value) as output will give you, in your example, the key "Address1" and as value an array `["Lane1", "Lane2"]`. Now you can easily access the elements over `value[0]` or `value[1]`. So for your needs just use `{{ value.join (',') }}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
{{value.join(", ")}}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/paoc5bvg/

Answer (score 0):

My idea is using join of JavaScript.  But if you do in view it will temper Application structure so you can do it like.

```
<td ng-repeat="(key,value) in results">limit(value)</td>
```

in controller you can define function like.

```
$scope.limit=function(value){return value.join(",")}
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

See this jsfiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/** and this thread [angularjs - ng-repeat: access key and value from JSON array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697695/angularjs-ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-from-json-array-object)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">{{key}}: {{val}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for helping me out.The solution saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one `ng-repeat` for rows and then another one for columns.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in results">
    <td ng-repeat="data in value">{{data}}</td>
</tr>
```

If that's not what you want, I guess you could join the last array.

```
{{value.join(', ')}}
```

Hope it helps.