# Cannot Display Object Contents - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make an app that will display the job details in the modal window, depending on the template that is selected. For this I have combined `ui.bootstrap` and `ui.router` . But for some reason, I cannot manage to display the objects as I would want to. I know that `$http.get` is working, as when I do the `console.log(specs)`, the object is displayed.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="car-up" ng-controller="carCtrl">
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="careersTpl.html">
        <div class="closer">
            <span class="close-me" ng-click="ok()">X</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span>{{placeholder}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body modtwo">
            <ul>
                <li><a ui-sref="sales">Sales Department</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a ui-sref="webd">Web Developer</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="crm">Client Relationship Manager</a></li>
                <li></li>

            </ul>
        <div class="show-me" ui-view></div>
        </div>
     </script> 
     <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open</button>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('carApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('webd', {
            url: "/web-developer",
            templateUrl: "templates/web-developer.html",
        })
        .state('crm', {
            url: "/crm",
            templateUrl: "templates/crm-uk.html"
        })
}]);
```

**ctrl.js**

```
app.controller('carCtrl', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {
    $http.get('jobs.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.placeholder = response.data.default;
        $scope.specs = response.data.specs;

        $scope.open = function() {

            var modalContent = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'careersTpl.html',
                controller : 'modalContentCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                size: 'lg',
                backdropClass: 'backdropOver',
                openedClass: 'modal-opened',
                resolve: { 
                    items: function() { return $scope.specs; },
                    items2: function() { return $scope.placeholder;}
                }
            })
        console.log($scope.placeholder);
        console.log($scope.specs);
        console.log($scope.specs.crm);
        }
    });
});

app.controller('modalContentCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, items2) {
    $scope.specs = items;
    $scope.placeholder = items2;
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
});
```

**crm-uk.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in specs.crm">
    <h3>{{v["job-title"]}}</h3>
    <p>{{v["job-body"]}}</p>
    Apply Here:
    <p>{{v["job-apply"]}}</p>
</div>
```

**web-developer.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in specs.web-dev">
    <h3>{{v["job-title"]}}</h3>
    <p>{{v["job-body"]}}</p>
    Apply Here:
    <p>{{v["job-apply"]}}</p>
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "default":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
   "specs":{
      "web-dev":{
         "job-title":"Web Developer",
         "job-body":"Lorem Ipsum Body Text",
         "job-apply":"applink"
      },
      "crm":{
         "job-title":"Client Relationship Manager",
         "job-body":"Lorem Ipsum CRM Text",
         "job-apply":"applylink"
      }
   }
}
```

I believe something is wrong with my `.json` file or how I am accessing it, but cannot figure out what.

Can someone please help?

thanks.

Comment: try <h3>{{v.job-title}}</h3>

Comment: Tried already, this is what I get in output: 
0

0
Apply Here:

0
0

0
Apply Here:

0
0

0
Apply Here:

0

Comment: And why is "Apply Here" repeated always..

Comment: I think you're iterating wrongly over the JSON key-values. Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697695/angularjs-ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-from-json-array-object) to know how to do this correctly.

Comment: Please post a working solution. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Can you create a Plunkr adding the jobs.json to the code so we can have a closer look , if provided a solution will be posted fairly quick ;)?

Comment: Here it is, but for some reason it's not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/BspIAJBkH2zSQPfupTyh

Comment: I've updated your plunkr to make it work, see solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First best to change the JSON structure as following:

```
{
    "default": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "specs": {
        "web-dev": [{
            "job-title": "Web Developer",
            "job-body": "Lorem Ipsum Body Text",
            "job-apply": "applink"
        }],
        "crm": [{
            "job-title": "Client Relationship Manager",
            "job-body": "Lorem Ipsum CRM Text",
            "job-apply": "applylink"
        }]
    }
}
```

Make the "crm" as a list of multiples.
Then in the view file, you can loop the "crm" specs list.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in specs.crm">
    {{item['job-title']}}<br/>
    {{item['job-body']}}<br/>
    {{item['job-apply']}}<br/>
</div>
```

Or use `{{::item['job-title']}}` for single data binding to limit digest cycles

Working [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCkstS6xoNbCoyN7q6mh?p=preview)
Please note only updated for 'CRM'

Comment: The `::` limits binding to only the first set of digest watcher. Meaning no continous watch is set on the view values used. More details can be found here https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/. It comes handy for data which does not change from within your application, and increase performance.

Comment: Thanks mate, first time to see this.

Comment: Just for the record I have managed to do this using `(k, v)` and then calling the value, ie.: `{{v["job-title"]}}`, etc.